# Devise 3.2.1custom redirect_to on Sign Up.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am working with Rails 4.0.1 and Devise 3.2.1.  After a user signs up I want to save their email address to the database. I then want to ask the user for additional information in the update action on a separate page.

How to I customer Devise's create action so that I redirect the user to the user/update controller action?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `after_sign_up_path_for` in a newly-created `RegistrationsController` to control where the user goes after they sign up.

The devise documentation has [a wiki article](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29) on how to do just this.

Comment: Thank you -  {I am getting closer.  'def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
end'